# Wordpress. Como rellenar los textos de una revista digital desde un formulario

Tags: wordpress

hola un cliente me pide una revista digital en wordpress, esta revista siempre llevara el mismo numero de páginas formato y eso, lo unico que habria que cambiar son los textos, esto seria desde un formulario para que le cliente no tubiera que tocar codigo. no se por donde empezar, sabeis de algun plugin o algo que pueda ayudarme a esta tarea??? o lo realizo desde cero??

Graciasss

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress hace esto por defecto, no hace falta plugin. De hecho esa es su esencia.

Tu cliente ya tiene un formulario. Solo debe cargar el contenido dentro del menu ENTRADAS, ahi solo cargara texto, fotos, video, etc . Todo similar a un editor de Texto.

Luego el diseñador debe maquetar el formato en que se ve ese contenido. En otras palabras hay que crear un Theme. Pero Wordpress guarda este contenido de texto en la base de datos y se suelen llamar POST.

Cuando el desarrollador arma el Theme (conjunto de paginas PHP) imprime dinamicamente lo que se haya cargado desde el menu Entradas en el escritorio de Wordpress. (se accede www.dominio.com/wp-admin)

Wordpress también admite crear usuarios con ciertos permisos. Esto es para evitar que por error toque algo del diseño, etc. entonces se le puede dar permisos solo para crear o editar notas.